# php mysql and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having 3 tables:

module_names (module_id,module_name)

- 1 | test_module
- 2 | test_module2
- 3 | test_module3

module_groups (group_id,group_name)

- 1 | group
- 2 | group2
- 3 | group3
- 4 | group4

modules_to_groups (module_id,group_id)

- 2|2
- 1|2
- 3|4

When i use GROUP_CONCAT in my query i getting the correct results

```
group2 -> test_module , test_module2
group4 -> test_module3
```

But i want:

```
group1 -> (no module added yet)
group2 -> test_module , test_module2
group3 -> (no module added yet)
group4 -> test_module3
```

The whole function i use:

```
function ListModuleGroups() {
global $admin,$prefix, $db, $admin_file;
OpenTable();
echo '<div><b>Groups and Modules :</b></div>';
$result = $db->sql_query("SELECT m.module_id, m.module_name, g.group_name, g.group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(m.module_name) from " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_groups g, " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_names m, " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_to_group m2g where m.module_id = m2g.module_id and m2g.group_id = g.group_id and g.group_id = g.group_id group by g.group_id");
while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
        $group_name = $row['group_name'];
        $module_name = $row['GROUP_CONCAT(m.module_name)'];

        echo "<div>".htmlentities($group_name). '--' . htmlentities($module_name)." </div>";
    }
CloseTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first there seems to be a weird condition in your SQL - g.group_id = g.group_id. Perhaps you may try to remove it.

Second, you should use LEFT JOIN for reading all groups. LEFT JOIN selects all records from the table on the left and only matching records from the table to the right. Please refer to MySQL docs for further reading.

Below code might help get desired resutls:

```
function ListModuleGroups() {
    global $admin,$prefix, $db, $admin_file;
    OpenTable();
    echo '<div><b>Groups and Modules :</b></div>';

    $result = $db->sql_query("SELECT g.group_name, GROUP_CONCAT(m.module_name) modules
    from " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_groups g
        LEFT JOIN " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_to_group m2g ON g.group_id = m2g.group_id 
        LEFT JOIN " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_names m ON m2g.module_id = m.module_id
    GROUP BY g.group_id");

    while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
            $group_name = $row['group_name'];
            if (!empty($row['modules'])) {
                $module_name = $row['modules'];
            } else {
                $module_name = '(no module added yet)';
            }
            echo "<div>".htmlentities($group_name). '--' . htmlentities($module_name)." </div>";
        }
    CloseTable();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank YOU!! , i accepted your answer cause you noticed the left over group_id=group_id and you wrote the complete function over. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` since you want to list all `module_groups`,

```
SELECT  a.Group_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.Module_Name)
FROM    module_group a
        LEFT JOIN modules_to_groups b
            ON a.group_id = b.group_id
        LEFT JOIN module_names c
            ON b.module_ID = c.module_ID
GROUP   BY a.Group_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80fde/3)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I of course had to up vote for pointing me to SQLFiddle and show me a working example.Also a BIG Thanks for you.(glad to know it also exist fiddle for sql) +1 for you to.